# DMN/FEEL (OMG) Implementation in Java

Tags: java

Is there any implementation of Friendly Enough Expression Language or any sub-parts of Decision Modeling Notation (DMN) defined by Object Modeling Group (OMG) in Java?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.